# SQL - Group by with having Result

Tags: sql

For the following table i need to fetch user who did min 2 distinct transactions and have sum of net sale equal to or more than 20,

[image]

But, everything need to be in same select cant use temp table, i am using the below query, but getting ambiguity in result,

```
select z.customer_nbr, transaction_nbr
from sales_transaction,
     (select customer_nbr
      from sales_transaction
      group by customer_nbr
      having count(transaction_nbr) >=2) z
group by z.customer_nbr, transaction_nbr
having sum(net_sales_rtl)>20
```

Below is the result

[image]

Result ambiguity - customer_numer have no transaction with no 16

Comment: Show us what you got and what you want to achieve (ie. in image). It will help us to provide you the solution more quickly.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images. And make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Hi Mahedi Sabuj - Thanks for reply, in result set why i am getting 16 transaction no for 100 customer number

Comment: If i take every thing in same query its works perfectly, question is why there is an ambiguity if there is outer query added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "user", I assume you mean the entity referred to by `customer_nbr`.

Your query is only looking at the net sales for a single transaction, not for the entire customer.

You seem to want aggregation and `having`:

```
select st.customer_nbr
from sales_transaction st
group by st.customer_nbr
having count(distinct st.transaction_nbr) >= 2 and
       sum(st.net_sales) > 20;
```

If you wanted *all* transactions to follow the `20` minimum, then two levels of aggregation would be appropriate:

```
select ct.customer_nbr
from (select st.customer_nbr, st.transaction_nbr, 
             sum(st.net_sales) as transaction_net_sales
      from sales_transaction st
      group by st.customer_nbr, st.transaction_nbr
     ) ct
group by ct.customer_nbr
having count(*) >= 2 and
       min(ct.transaction_net_sales) > 20;
```

Comment: This works perfectly if you have to select customer_nbr only, but i want to pass the customer_number to my outer query where i want to compare the net sale amount, there i am getting ambiguity

Comment: @VenkateshPatil . . . Just add a `where` clause if you want only one customer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is missing here is a join between the results from sales_transaction and the subquery z.

Considering both your tables share column transaction_nbr, you could have something like this:

```
select z.customer_nbr, s.transaction_nbr
from sales_transaction s,
     (select customer_nbr, transaction_nbr
      from sales_transaction
      group by customer_nbr, transaction_nbr
      having count(transaction_nbr) >=2) z
where z.transaction_nbr = s.transaction_nbr
group by z.customer_nbr, transaction_nbr
having sum(net_sales_rtl)>20
```

Comment: Hey sorry the inner query table is sales_transaction